# Add values to specific points in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

In order to create the global stiffness matrix of a truss, I need to overlay the stiffness matrix to the global one.
I started by creating a zero matrix

```
K=zeros(6,6); %Empty global stiffness matrix
```

And then I want to overlay a 4x4 matrix (Ke) to the correct position. For example:

```
Ke(1,1)->K(1,1)
Ke(1,2)->K(1,2)
Ke(1,3)->K(1,5)
Ke(1,4)->K(1,6)
Ke(2,1)->K(2,1)
Ke(2,2)->K(2,2)
Ke(2,3)->K(2,5)
Ke(2,4)->K(2,6)
etc.
```

I found a piece of code that would work but I'm afraid I can't understand why. Here it is:

```
sctr = [2*n1-1 2*n1 2*n2-1 2*n2];
K(sctr,sctr) = K(sctr,sctr) + Ke;
```

Following my above example `n1`, `n2` should be `n1=1` and `n2=3`. The n1 and n2 correspond to the start and finish node of the element. Of course this would be inside a loop that will calculate the stiffness matrix of each element and overlay it to the global matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given values of `n1` and `n2`, `sctr` is

```
sctr = [1 2 5 6];
```

This corresponds with the row and column indices you want to change. `K(sctr,sctr)` selects the 4x4 submatrix of `K`. Matlab selects one element for each possible combination of the elements in `sctr`. So, for each selected row (i.e. which have their index in `sctr`) the columns with their index in `sctr` are selected. See [matrix indexing](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) for more information.